# How to avoid block code when ColorStream in called

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, skeleton-code

I have a WPF application, it use a Kinect for traking skeleton, so I have this code

```
this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
```

If I run my application for many times and stop application within VisualStudio (debug terminator button) I have some trouble, the debug remains locked at this line code:

```
this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
```

as long as I removed USB cable of the Kinect device, which allows the debugger to go to the next line code.

Can we help me?